# How to add a collection of input.value to a state hook?

Tags: reactjs

why am I only adding a password? How to add all values ​​to a "data"?
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-dan-f10pz (auth/signIn)
https://f10pz.csb.app/signin (my form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is using a `useState` hook that's an object with multiple keys, but you're updating only one key. If you change:

`setData({[e.target.id]: e.target.value});`

to

`setData({...data, [e.target.id]: e.target.value});`

It'll basically spread whatever the state is AND update the key/value pair of what you're passing in. That way, your data contains both values. As a side note, next time, maybe post a piece of your code instead of a link to the sandbox. Just makes things easier!

Some reading material:

- [Spread Operator](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html)
- [Immutability](https://blog.logrocket.com/immutability-in-react-ebe55253a1cc/)